# Change string to only one line i csv

Tags: csv, delphi, pascal, lazarus, freepascal

I have csv file where each record is one line. Problem is that sometimes one cell have few lines. For example:

```
 first;second;third;something something something something;four
 first;second;third;something
 something 
 something something;four
```

I opened this in Notepad++ and i see that end of record has LF white tag and new lines in cell has CR white tag.

How can I remove this CR white tags? I would like to have after convert:

```
first;second;third;something something something something;four
first;second;third;something something something something;four
```

Comment: Your description indicates that the file should not have any `CR`s at all. So, if this is a one time fix you need to do, use Notepad++ to search in extended search mode for `\r` and replace with nothing (or a space it that is missing from the file. If this problem is reoccuring, yous should correct the source of the problem. If you want to fix this programmatically in your program, scan the data and delete all `CR`s

Comment: Thanks - how should I find CRs? StringReplace(MyString, ????, '');

Comment: Are you sure that these CRs are not part of the content? Maybe these columns contain multi line strings.

Comment: @Zhorov No, CR is #13, not #10. With your code he would remove the LFs. s := StringReplace(s, #13, '', [rfReplaceAll]) would remove CR.

Comment: @dummzeuch Sorry, my mistake. Of course CR is #13, so  s := StringReplace(s, #13, '', [rfReplaceAll]). Thanks for this comment.

Comment: Based on the example given, any `#13` not preceded by `#32` (space) would have to be replaced with `#32` instead of an empty string. You won't be able to do that with a single call to `StringReplace()`, but you could use two calls: `s := StringReplace(s, ' '#13, ' ', [rfReplaceAll]); s := StringReplace(s, #13, ' ', [rfReplaceAll]);` Personally, I would opt to just find (or write) an actual CSV parser instead, and let it handle replacing the `#13`s while parsing and not reinserting them while saving.

Answer (score 1):

Answer 1: Provided you can uniquely identify where you want to remove the newline

Find: “(Pattern 1 at end of line)\r\n” - Replace with “\1”

Or Find: “(Pattern 1 at end of line)\r\n(Pattern 2 at start of next line)\” - Replace with “\1\2”

Answer 2: Instead if you can identify where you want to keep the newlines

Find: “(Pattern 1 at end of line)” – Replace with “\1QAZ” where “QAZ” is not anywhere in the file. Continue until "QAZ" is everywhere you require

Remove all new lines by Find “\r\n” – Replace with nothing.

Restore required new lines by Find “QAZ” – replace with “\n” – windows Notepad++ does not need the \r